# creating sqlite3 dump files with all table values

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-dump

I can generate a sqlite3 dump file with

```
sqlite3 app.db .dump > app_dump.sql
```

however, if there is a row in that database which has no entry it is just left out in the dump file. This is a problem when using the dump file to read the data into another database. Is there a way to force the dump file to have all values defined in the table? So if there is no entry it just uses empty string '' or something like that?
thanks 
carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `.dump` always includes all table rows:

```
sqlite> create table t(x);
sqlite> insert into t values (null), (0), (''), (x'');
sqlite> select * from t;

0


sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE t(x);
INSERT INTO "t" VALUES(NULL);
INSERT INTO "t" VALUES(0);
INSERT INTO "t" VALUES('');
INSERT INTO "t" VALUES(X'');
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes or from the sqlite3 cli:

```
sqlite> .output app_dump.sql
sqlite> .dump <OPTIONAL table_name>

sqlite> .read app_dump.sql
```

File will be in your current path else locate it
e.g `C:/sql/app_dump.sql` or `./app_dump.sql`

If it rearranges your columns e.g `.header on` does not match data then:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
RENAME COLUMN current_name TO new_name;
```